# nginx reverse proxy configuration for a subdomain is reset to default randomly, on a server managed by Plesk

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, plesk

We have a VPS managed by Plesk. We have apache2 and Nginx installed on it. We use Nginx as a reverse proxy server for our spring-boot applications hosted on other VPS. For that, we create subdomains for each spring-boot application. After the configuration, everything works fine.

But, for some reason, our configurations for each subdomain are reset to the default configuration randomly and frequently. Thus all the subdomains lead to the Plesk home page. We don't understand how this happens or know how to solve it.

Please, we need some help.

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say the VPS is "managed" by Plex, Do you mean hosted, perhaps? What do the logs say? Have contacted Plex for support? Is this a supported service on their systems?

Comment: It is Plesk, not Plex, my bad. We use the Plesk control panel to manage the server. We haven't contacted Plesk support yet.